# Looking for a service-oriented email/notification broker for custom application portfolio

Tags: c#, java, .net, email

My team maintains/develops several custom .NET and Java applications. Most of these applications need to send occasional operational notifications (usually as email routed through our company's Exchange server) but each application has its own implementation. It seems to make that it would make more sense to have a service dedicated to this functionality that is consumable by all of our custom apps (and any future ones we might build) so as to reduce the number of points of failure if nothing else. I'd love to hear suggestions on any off the shelf products that facilitate this need as well as any homegrown solutions you may have used.

Thanks in advance!

Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need a commercial product?

1. Write a web service in your favorite language
2. Create Java and .NET clients by importing the WSDL

EDIT: I'd stick to primitive types for service parameters. All the service has to do is send mail.

Comment: I agree that building likely prospers over buying in this particular instance as the scope of needs is pretty narrow. I'm just wondering if there is a cheap gold standard for this sort of thing of which I'm totally unaware. 

I should also say that building a comprehensive solution -- one that can handle non-deliverables, network hiccups, and other challenges properly -- could be a substantial undertaking.

Comment: @Patrick - agreed, if you want *reliable* delivery that's more difficult. We've implemented something similar using an underlying database table that acts as a queue. We can review the queue for delivery failures (or have a tool like Microsoft's System Center Operations Manager monitor it).

Comment: I was thinking of using a DB queue as well. Reliability is important as, sadly, our organization's IT infrastructure leaves much to be desired. Fortunately, reliability is a tenet of contemporary SOA so a properly thought-out design should take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a WCF service to handle brokering messages in this manner. It allows you to use many different protocols and is very robust.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to use BasicHttpBinding to consume it from Java, though? That would limit your access to WCF features.

Comment: I'm not sure what Java would need to consume it but that's just the transmission method. If you're referring to having a service that has communication via a protocol that allows sessions (such as tcp), yes http is naturally sessionless. WCF does have a type of binding (can't think of it off the top of my head ATM) that allows http transmissions utilize sessions. I'm not sure if Java could interface with that but I think it's irrelevant. You're asking a service to propagate messages. Your apps could connect, pass the message content to the service and be done with it. It's pretty simple.